# Defining global objects using YUI Doc

Tags: javascript, yui, yuidoc

How to define a global variable using YUI Doc. I can't find suitable comment tag to define a global object and its properties. What is the best way to do it. Below is my defined object:

```
var glob = glob || {
    breakPoints: {
        mainNavigation: 840
    },
    animation: {
        speed: {
            slow: 1000
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? YUI is meant to be used without tainting the global object (except for the Y property). If YUI instances have to talk to each other, maybe you should refactor your code.

Comment: No no. This is not YUI library. This is regarding YUI doc. I'm using YUI doc to document my javascript. So YUI doc has specific comment tags that used to generate JS documentation. Within that tags I can't find a suitable tag name to describe global object. Please look at their syntax [reference](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/syntax/)

Comment: @Ryxle Did you find a way to do this?